# Contextmenu Radio buttons issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am working on an google chrome app which makes use of contextmenu. My contextmenu contains a bunch of entries some of which are nested. My issue is with such a nested menu in which the child elements are radio buttons. My app also provides shortcuts to loop through these options. So in my JS, I have written the code so that the context menu is updated to properly reflect the current selection. So basically

```
 Parent --> Child Radio 1 (Selected)   Parent --> Child Radio 1
            Child Radio 2                         Child Radio 2 (Selected)
            Child Radio 3                         Child Radio 3

        [Before Shortcut Press]               [After Shortcut Press]
```

When I call the chrome.contextMenus.update function with proper id and options, the update occurs only when its is progressive i.e from child 1 to 2 or 2 to 3 and so on. If I go the other way around, no update occurs. The function doesn't throw any error as well. Maybe I have misunderstood the purpose of using radio buttons. I just want it to update either way. Also, once I update the last child to be the selected one, it gets stuck. Doesn't move either way after that.

```
//Code to handle shortcut
chrome.contextMenus.update(radioUniqueID, { 'checked': true });
```

This is how I initially create the menu.

```
for(i = 0; i < t.playlist.length; i++) {
   chrome.contextMenus.create({ 'title': t.playlist[i].name, 'type': 'radio', 'parentId': parentID, 'id': 'play' + i});
}
```

Comment: Posting your code would help.

Comment: Unchecking the current entry by updating it and then checking the new one seems to work. Weird but works.

Comment: `Unchecking the current entry by updating it and then checking the new one` seems absolutely natural to me. It's a plain straightforward implementation. Of course, API could be smarter than that.

Comment: It worked one way so I guess its natural for me to expect it to work the other way as well. Besides, having to uncheck the old one and then check the new seems like checkbox functionality.

Comment: Yeah, the API is primitive and doesn't uncheck the previous one automatically. In a better world it should do it, of course, so maybe you can submit a feature request on bugs.chromium.org.